# Close Android Application

Tags: android

Please suggest how I may close my whole Android Application with one line code.

Comment: why would you stipulate that it must be in one line of code? It will most likely take more than that.

Answer (score 85):

Yes - Why, then how(sort of):

Short answer:

```
System.exit(0);
```

This nicely and cleanly terminates the whole java machine which is dedicated to running the app. However, you should do it from the main activity, otherwise android may restart your app automatically. (Tested this on Android 7.0)

Details and explanation of why this is a good question and a programmer may have a very legitimate reason to terminate their app this way:

I really don't see the gain in speaking harshly to someone who's looking for a way to terminate their app.

Good is a friendly reminder to beginners that on Android you don't have to worry about closing your app -- but some people actually do want to terminate their app even though they know that they don't have to -- and their question of how to do so is a legitimate  question with a valid answer.

Perhaps many folks live in an ideal world and don't realize that there's a real world where real people are trying to solve real problems.

The fact is that even with android, it is still a computer and that computer is still running code, and that it is perfectly understandable why someone may wish to truly exit their "app" (i.e. all of the activities and resources belonging to their app.)

It is true that the developers at Google designed a system where they believed nobody would ever need to exit their app. And maybe 99% of the time they are right!

But one of the amazing things about allowing millions of programmers to write code for a platform is that some of them will try to push the platform to its limits in order to do amazing things! -- Including things that the Android Developers never even dreamed of!

There is another need for being able to close a program, and that is for troubleshooting purposes. That is what brought me to this thread: I'm just learning how to utilize the audio input feature to do realtime DSP.

Now don't forget that I said the following: I well know that when I have everything done right, I won't need to kill my app to reset the audio interface.

BUT: Remember, perfect apps don't start out as perfect apps! They start out as just barely working apps and grow to become proper ideal apps.

So what I found was that my little audio oscilloscope test app worked great until I pressed the android  Home button. When I then re-launched my oscilloscope app, there was no audio coming in anymore.

At first I would go into 
`Settings->Applications->Manage Applications->AppName->Force Stop.`

(Note that if the actual linux process is not running, the Force Stop button will be disabled. If the button is enabled, then the Linux process is still running!)

Then I could re-launch my app and it worked again.

At first, I was just using divide by zero to crash it - and that worked great.
But I decided to look for a better way - which landed me here!

So here's the ways I tried and what I found out:

Background:
Android runs on Linux. 
Linux has processes and process IDs (PIDs) just like Windows does, only better.
To see what processes are running on your android (with it connected into the USB and everything) run `adb shell top` and you will get an updating list of all the processes running in the linux under the android.

If you have linux on your PC as well, you can type

`adb shell top | egrep -i '(User|PID|MyFirstApp)' --line-buffered`

to get just the results for your app named MyFirstApp. You can see how many Linux Processes are running under that name and how much of the cpu power they are consuming.

(Like the task manager / process list in Windows)

Or if you want to see just the running apps:

`adb shell top | egrep -i '(User|PID|app_)' --line-buffered`

You can also kill any app on your device by running 
`adb shell kill 12345` 
where 12345 is it's PID number.

From what I can tell, each single-threaded app just uses a single Linux process.

So what I found out was that (of course) if I just activate the android Home option, my app continues to run.
And if I use the `Activity.finish()`, it still leaves the process running.
Divide by zero definitely terminates the linux process that is running.
Killing the PID from within the app seems the nicest so far that I've found, at least for debugging purposes.

I initially solved my need to kill my app by adding a button that would cause a divide by zero, like this in my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public void exit(View view)
{
    int x;
    x=1/0;
}
```

Then in my layout XML file section for that button I just set the android:onClick="exit".

Of course divide by zero is messy because it always displays the "This application stopped..." or whatever.

So then I tried the finish, like this:

```
public void exit(View view)
{
    finish();
}
```

And that made the app disappear from the screen but it was still running in the background.

Then I tried:

```
public void exit(View view)
{
      android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

So far, this is the best solution I've tried.

UPDATE: This is the same as above in that it instantly terminates the Linux process and all threads for the app:

```
public void exit(View view)
{
      System.exit(0);
}
```

It instantly does a nice full exit of the thread in question without telling the user that the app crashed.

All memory used by the app will be freed. (Note: Actually, you can set parameters in your manifest file to cause different threads to run in different Linux processes, so it gets more complicated then.)

At least for quick and dirty testing, if you absolutely need to know that the thread is actually fully exited, the kill process does it nicely. However, if you are running multiple threads you may have to kill each of those, probably from within each thread.

EDIT: Here is a great link to read on the topic:
`http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html`
It explains how each app runs in its own virtual machine, and each virtual machine runs under its own user ID.

Here's another great link that explains how (unless specified otherwise in manifest) an app and all of its threads runs in a single Linux process: `http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html`

So as a general rule, an app really is a program running on the computer and the app really can be fully killed, removing all resources from memory instantly.

(By instantly I mean ASAP -- not later whenever the ram is needed.)

PS: Ever wonder why you go to answer your android phone or launch your favorite app and it freezes for a second? Ever reboot because you get tired of it? That's probably because of all the apps you ran in the last week and thought you quit but are still hanging around using memory. Phone kills them when it needs more memory, causing a delay before whatever action you wanted to do!

Update for Android 4/Gingerbread:  Same thing as above applies, except even when an app exits or crashes and its whole java virtual machine process dies, it still shows up as running in the app manager, and you still have the "force close" option or whatever it is. 4.0 must have an independent list of apps it thinks is running rather than actually checking to see if an app is really even running.

Comment: Hey,

You don't have many points here, but I wanted to say thanks for this long and helpful answer. "You don't need to do this" (currently the top answer) is more or less useless without a further explanation. Your answer actually explains exactly what I needed.

Comment: No need for any fancy codes, just try `System.exit(0)` to quit an Android application. This is basically the Java command that Android had supported/ported across. After all, Android is basically Java plus a few other things. :)

Comment: Yes! Thanks! System.exit(0) is definitely the best way. I had written most of the above before finding out about System.exit() but I left it to help people understand the situation better. Thanks!

Comment: @JesseGordon: I have the same requirement to kill the app.I used System.exit(0) and it works.Though at times I get the crash dialog- 'Unfortunately <app name> has stopped' (which I don't want to come).How can I prevent/avoid that dialog.And does the 'kill process ' function the same as System.exit(0)?

Comment: @Basher51: That's an interesting problem. I only would expect the "Unfortunately.." message if the app performs a violation of some sort, not if it cleanly exits with System.exit(0)... My guess is that maybe you are having another code issue that is causing a violation like dividing an integer by zero or something. Try running the app via the debugger in Eclipse so you can see the error message details when the app exits. Sorry I don't have anything more helpful! ~Jesse

Comment: I used the exception throwing method

Answer (score 12):

You could finish your Activity by calling [Activity.finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29). However take care of the [Android Activity life-cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: i want whole activities are finished by single call

Comment: yes, but it only closes one activity, not all activities that belong to the application.

Comment: finish() only closes that activity, but leaves everything else and the java virtual machine running. system.exit(0) closes the whole app.

Comment: is there any way to close the application itself, rather close activity only?

Comment: Good call. It is useful for single activity app. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could close your Android Application by calling System.exit(0).

Comment: This is correct. Each app runs in its own Java Virtual Machine, which is a single Linux process/task. System.exit(0) terminates the Java Virtual Machine which is running that app, and closes it completely. Otherwise, the JVM and the app will stay in memory for days or weeks.

Comment: This should be the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

just call the finish() in the method you would like to end the activity in, for example when you use the onCreate() method, in the end of the method, just add finish() and you will see the activity ends as soon as it is created!

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, finish function close the current displayed screen only.

Refer this [example](http://www.anddev.org/how_to_close_an_application-t1528.html) (where see the answer given by 'plusminus'), it will sure help you to close your application.

Answer (score 2):

Before doing so please read this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238) too:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

This code kill the process from OS
Using this code disturb the OS. So I would recommend you to use the below code

```
this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you mean by "close app". In android's terms its either about an "activity", or a group of activities in a temporal/ancestral order called "task".

End activity: just call `finish()`

End task:

1. clear activity task-stack
2. navigate to root activity
3. then call finish on it.

This will end the entire "task"

Answer (score 1):

not a one-line-code solution, but pretty easy:

sub-class Activity, then override and add finish() to onPause() method

this way, activity will be gone once it enters background, therefore the app won't keep a stack of activities, you can finish() the current activity and the app is gone!

Answer (score 0):

If you close the main Activity using `Activity.finish()`, I think it will close all the activities.
MAybe you can override the default function, and implement it in a static way, I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in one line of code. Try opening your activities with startActivityForResult. As the result you can pass something like a CLOSE_FLAG, which will inform your parent activity that its child activity has finished.

That said, you should probably read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238).

Comment: system.exit(0) does it very nicely in one line of code. Kills the whole JVM which is devoted to running that app.

Answer (score -2):

That's one of most useless desires of beginner Android developers, and unfortunately it seems to be very popular. How do you define "close" an Android application? Hide it's user interface? Interrupt background work? Stop handling broadcasts?

Android applications are a set of modules, bundled in an .apk and exposed to the system trough AndroidManifest.xml. Activities can be arranged and re-arranged trough different task stacks, and finish()-ing or any other navigating away from a single Activity may mean totally different things in different situations. Single application can run inside multiple processes, so killing one process doesn't necessary mean there will be no application code left running. And finally, BroadcastReceivers can be called by the system any time, recreating the needed processes if they are not running.

The main thing is that you **don't need** to stop/kill/close/whatever your app trough a single line of code. Doing so is an indication you missed some important point in Android development. If for some bizarre reason you have to do it, you need to finish() all Activities, stop all Services and disable all BroadcastReceivers declared in AndroidManifest.xml. That's not a single line of code, and maybe launching the Activity that uninstalls your own application will do the job better.

Comment: I don't believe this is a useful answer. He didn't ask for your opinion(which is not completely correct).  An example of why you would need to do this is if you have an Uncaught Exception Handler that sends the exception to a web server then closes the application after informing the user what had to be done.

Comment: This is not a useless desire. Android leaves finished() apps hanging around in memory for weeks or days if they aren't actually closed, using up memory. As a rule, each app runs entirely within its own java virtual machine, which is a single Linux process, running under its own user ID. When the JVM dies, the app is 100% closed. System.exit(0) terminates the JVM and the app. Activity.finish() does notfully close out the app, and leaves it and its JVM running in memory.

Comment: It's not true that each app runs entirely in it's own process - each app runs in at least one process, but may have more. Android OS doesn't immediately free the app's memory once the UI is gone away for several good reasons. You just need to upgrade your knowledge about Android before adapting such methods in your programming: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes

Comment: ognian, As a rule, each app does indeed run entirely in its own process. An advanced programmer can launch multiple threads as multiple processes, but according to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html, "By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and most applications should not change this."  So when a beginner asks if he can completely close his app - he probably isn't going to all the work of launching different threads in different processes.

Comment: ognian, Also, you mention that Android has several good reasons to not free an app's resources. However, it would be more accurate that some kinds of apps do give better user experience when they stay loaded, and for those there is reason to keep them loaded.  However, there are kinds of apps that don't need to keep loaded. There is no reason whatsoever to tie up memory from an app that I ran last week and aint gonna run for a month! When I launch an app I want to run, I want it to launch -- without having to wait for Android to finally close all the apps I've used once in the last 30 days!

Comment: @JesseGordon : The memory that is allocated to background apps is always available to the active apps, when they actually need it. It is not lost resource by any means, freeing it prematurely won't bring any benefits for the current and potential active apps. However populating it again with proper data for bringing a inactive app to the top have two impacts: delay in launch and wasting battery life. Freeing memory when actually needed is one of the good decisions that folks from Google made.

Comment: @ognian : No, memory allocated for use by one Linux process simply cannot be used by another Linux process until first process is completely closed out. If you ssh into your android device and run top,you can see that each app, whether foreground or background, is using so much memory. That memory is not "available" until after Android is requested that app to do its shutdown sequence (if any) and closed itself out. And that all takes time. Thus, when you go to launch an app, you will have to wait longer for it to launch if other apps have to be killed first.

Comment: @JesseGordon: You, sir are simply refusing to accept a good chunk of knowledge :) I believe that what Google developers publish about their own OS should be considered the most accurate, and there is no need to treat your speculations as the real thing. I guess that now and then somebody like you keeps on believing that their observation  is correct regardless of all what the official docs say, so Google guys have to write long and convincing articles in attempt to get such people back to reality. If this one doesn't change your mind, nothing will: http://bit.ly/aKmk2Q

Comment: @ognian : Thanks for the link to the blog post from 2010. What I've said here simply is not speculation. By way of background, I've been using Linux at the command line level for over a decade, and I know my way around it reasonably well by now. It is not just my speculation that Android runs in Linux, or that the memory allocated to one linux process simply cannot be used by another until first frees it. It is also fact that "By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and most applications should not change this."  Have you ever ssh'ed into android device?

Comment: @ognian: Pretty much everything I'm saying can be found in google's own document here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html, including the fact that Android runs Linux. However, if you don't understand how Linux works you may not understand how Android works. But Linux is like Mac and Windows: A process uses malloc to request RAM from the OS and is granted exclusive use of that ram. No other process is granted use of that ram unless first process frees it or is killed. And that's not a matter of opinion :) If you find contradicting google doc show me =) Tnx!