# Notification opens activity and I need to close it after

Tags: android, notifications

I got a Service which sends a Notification.
When you click on the notification, it opens an Activity.
I want to close this Activity when I click on a Button.
I used `finish();` but it closes the Activity and open the main activity of the application.
I'm not sure how to close it and it get back to the last "screen/application"

Comment: Use `finishAndRemoveTask()` available from API 21.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15652384/4935567) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just route to the page you want to open inside the onClickListener of the button where you are calling the finish()

Something like this

```
Button buttonX = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonXName);
buttonX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //  DesiredActivity is the activity you want to open on click
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DesiredActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } 
});
```

Comment: I found the solution: this.finishAffinity();

Comment: BTW: `this.` can be ommited

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to finish directly; you need `onBackPressed()` because you are coming this Activity from nowhere(phone's main screen/another app).

So when you call `onBackPressed()` it will close app :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    //supportFinishAfterTransition(); finish activity after going back 
    //if want overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nothing, R.anim.slide_out_right); 
}
```

Additionally you can add `supportFinishAfterTransition()` after `super.onBackPressed()` line  still if you want to finish your Activity.

After adding, call this method  : `onBackPressed()` in your `onClick` method, in this way you can add custom transitions too.